# Take user input and write to file from javascript inside a pdf?

Tags: javascript, pdf

Is it possible to have a pdf file that asks a user a set of questions and then writes their answers to a file, then next time it is viewed loads those answers as default values?  I know pdfs can include javascript and have figured out how to add javascript to a pdf with iText (http://itextpdf.com/) but don't know how to prompt for user input or write to a file from inside the pdf.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [jsPDF](http://jspdf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/basic.htm) to create PDFs via JavaScript on the fly! Yes, it is cool.